# What information does the numerical norm provide (and why)?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals, ideal-class-group

For an algebraic number field $K$ with ring of integers $_K$, the *numerical norm* $ℕ()$ of an ideal $⊆_K$ is defined to be the (finite) index of abelian groups $[_K:]$, or equivalently $|_K/|$.

Why is $_K/$ a useful thing to look at? Exactly what does $ℕ()$ tell you about $$? In particular, when and why is it true that $ℕ()=p$ means that $p_K=$ for some other ideal $$?

Comment: It's connected to the element norms in $O_K$ (if you take principal ideals, $N((\alpha)) = |N(\alpha)|$). It's also multiplicative for ideals (not that obvious). If $N(a) = p$ is a prime (not a prime power), then $p$ would be a maximal ideal in $O_K$, and therefore prime...

Answer (score 3):

Don't focus only on the norm of an ideal in isolation, but also on the norm mapping on all ideals. Using norms of ideals in the integers of a number field $K$ leads to the zeta-function of $K$:
$$
\zeta_K(s) = \sum_{\mathfrak a} \frac{1}{{\rm N}(\mathfrak a)^s}
$$
when ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$.  This is a pretty useful construction.

In modular arithmetic in $\mathbf Z$ we have the well-known formula
$$
\varphi(m) = m\prod_{p \mid m} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right),
$$
where $\varphi(m) = |(\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^\times|$. It turns out that there's an analogous formula for the units modulo a (nonzero) ideal in the integers of every number field:
$$
|({\mathcal O_K}/\mathfrak a)^\times| = {\rm N}(\mathfrak a)\prod_{\mathfrak p\mid \mathfrak a}\left(1 - \frac{1}{{\rm N}(\mathfrak p)}\right).
$$

Norms in various senses show up all over the place in number theory.  It might as well be called "norm theory".

Comment: Interesting, thanks very much!